# The resource cannot be found when use global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, global-asax

after i upload my web site in website panle i get this error
The resource cannot be found.

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /.aspx

i think its related to global.asax because when i remove it from host my web site run currectly
my global.asax code

```
namespace officeWeb
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String fullOrigionalpath = Request.Url.ToString();
            String[] sElements = fullOrigionalpath.Split('/');
            String[] sFilePath = sElements[sElements.Length - 1].Split('.');

            if (!fullOrigionalpath.Contains("__browserLink"))
            {
                            //Rewrite
            if (!fullOrigionalpath.Contains(".aspx") && sFilePath.Length == 1)
            {
                Context.RewritePath(sFilePath[0] + ".aspx");
            }
            }

        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            routes.Add("",
                new Route("root/pages/service/{*pathInfo}", new WebServiceRouteHandler("~/root/config/services.asmx")));

        }


        public class WebServiceRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
        {
            private static IHttpHandlerFactory ScriptHandlerFactory;
            static WebServiceRouteHandler()
            {
                var assembly = typeof(System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute).Assembly;
                var type = assembly.GetType("System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory");
                ScriptHandlerFactory = (IHttpHandlerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
            }

            private string virtualPath;
            public WebServiceRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
            {
                this.virtualPath = virtualPath;
            }

            public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
            {
                string pathInfo = requestContext.RouteData.Values["pathInfo"] as 
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathInfo))
                    pathInfo = string.Format("/{0}", pathInfo);

                requestContext.HttpContext.RewritePath(this.virtualPath, pathInfo, requestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToString());
                var handler = ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext.Current, requestContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, this.virtualPath, requestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(this.virtualPath));
                return handler;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do?
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the requested URL, it reads `/.aspx`. That is an invalid URL, since it misses the actual file name and only has the extension.

You need to debug your code and see if the variable values in `Application_BeginRequest()` are what you expect them to are. Likely they aren't.

Comment: thank's for your asnswer,but when i remove my code in global.asax put empty gloabl.asax in root i get same error, in local host its work correctly

Comment: I'm confused. Does it work without global.asax, or does it not work without that? In your question, you said it worked without, now you say it doesn't work without.

Comment: when i removed this from host it work, and when i add this to host it's dosent work (i localhost its work Either)